# JQuery select children without specific class

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I select text of all visible span elements that, that is those who do not have ng-hide class on itself or its ascendant?

The output should be: "C"

```
<div>
   <span class="ng-hide ng-binding ng-etc">
      <span>A</span>
   </span>
   <span>
      <span class="ng-hide">B</span>
      <span>C</span>
   </span>
<div>
```

I started with this but it does not check the parent:

```
$("div").children(":not(.ng-hide)").text();
```

Comment: Not very clear: The second enclosing `<span><span class="ng-hide">B</span><span>C</span></span>` span satisfies your condition here. (doesn't have `ng-hide` and doesn't have a parent with `ng-hide`)

Comment: That is why I asked the question, my initial script does not check the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$('div span').filter(function() {
  return (
     $(this).children().length == 0 //span with no children
    && $(this).closest('.ng-hide').length == 0 //span with no .ng-hide or no parents with the class
  );
}).text();
```

```js
alert($('div span').filter(function() {
  return (
     $(this).children().length == 0 
    && $(this).closest('.ng-hide').length == 0
  );
}).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="ng-hide ng-binding ng-etc">
      <span>A</span>
  </span>
  <span>
      <span class="ng-hide">B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  </span>
  <div>
```

Comment: Nice `$(this).children().length == 0`, you may also need to add `$(this).closest('.ng-hide').length == 0`. From OP: _those who do not have ng-hide class on itself or its ascendant_

Comment: @SelvakumarArumugam I just did. Thanks. :D

Comment: Very close, but see https://jsfiddle.net/nfdkhry7/1.  It should alert **C**, but the `children().length` logic prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div span:not(.ng-hide):not:(has(*)) span:not(.ng-hide)").text();
```

Note that in case you have multiple elements returned by this expression, you have to fetch the .text() of each one of them separately with an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/not/ - documentation

There is some mistakes in your code, correct version:

```
  $("span").not("span.ng-hide").map(function(element){
        console.log(element.text());
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '';

$("div span:not(.ng-hide)").each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('.ng-hide').length || $(this).has('.ng-hide').length)
        return;

    text += $(this).text();
});

console.log(text);
```

This collects them all into one array, you may want to collect them into something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the node and remove the clone's `.ng-hide` descendants:

```js
var c = $('div').clone();
c.find('.ng-hide').remove();
console.log(c.text().trim());  //C
c.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span class="ng-hide ng-binding ng-etc">
      <span>A</span>
   </span>
   <span>
      <span class="ng-hide">B</span>
      <span>C</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

If cloning the node is too expensive in terms of speed or memory, you can take advantage of [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)'s feature of returning only visible text.

Although `Node.innerText` is non-standard, it's supported by all browsers and is unlikely to go away.

```js
$('div .ng-hide').hide();
console.log($('div')[0].innerText);  //C
$('div .ng-hide').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span class="ng-hide ng-binding ng-etc">
      <span>A</span>
   </span>
   <span>
      <span class="ng-hide">B</span>
      <span>C</span>
   </span>
</div>
```